# How to view image saved on SD Card in Android from Emulator or Eclipse?

Tags: android

Is there any way to view image saved on SD Card without any coding from Emulator or eclipse.
Thanks

Comment: belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file explorer in Eclipse to pull the file from the sdcard of the emulator to your local drive then view it.  Or you could use adb command line to copy it

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone to your computer and choose "Data Storage". Here you are, you can browse your sdcard from explorer(if you're using windows).